# Add a custom property to include in all log4net messages

Tags: log4net, properties

I have a unique identifier which goes through the whole application. I want this 'ID' to be logged as a separate property, so that it's easy to find out in log files or from the database.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use [context properties](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Log4Net-Tutorial-pt-6-Log-Event-Context.aspx) e.g. like this:

```
ThreadContext.Properties["ID"] = yourID;
```

then you can access the property in the pattern string like this:

```
%property{ID}
```